# Is there a way to change language in django-mdeditor

Tags: django, markdown

I'm using django-mdeditor and it works fine just as i expect the only problem is the language. I believe its Chinese. How can I change it to English?

[image]

Comment: Anybody please?

Comment: I have answered your question. Did you find a way to render the mark-down content in the front-end?

Comment: Yes though some does not render well. Should I show you how I did it?

Comment: Not needed now :) You can refer to this `HTML` file - https://github.com/pylixm/django-mdeditor/blob/master/mdeditor_demo_app/templates/show.html, on how to render the markdown content in the front-end. 

I think I will write a small blog post where I will consolidate all my findings on `django-mdeditor` :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In django-mdeditor 0.1.16 according to ../site-packages/mdeditor/configs.py in project settings:

```
MDEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    ...
    'language': 'en',
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an English translation available. You can find the corresponding JS file here: https://github.com/pylixm/django-mdeditor/blob/master/mdeditor/static/mdeditor/languages/en.js

So, just including `<script src="/static/mdeditor/languages/en.js"></script>`
 at the end of your template would do the job.

I have tested it locally (as I am also using `mdeditor` in one of my projects :D).

If that does not work, you can always download the script into the static folder of the project and include it in your template using the `static` tag.

Comment: Thank you it works! but how would I use it in default admin site?

Comment: There are instructions here - https://github.com/pylixm/django-mdeditor#use-the-markdown-widget-in-admin, on how to use `mdeditor` in the admin site.